# jquery-ui-map fit bounds with a polyline?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, google-polyline, jquery-ui-map

I'm working on a mobile app using jQuery Mobile. I also you the plugin "jquery-ui-map" to do my map (that helped alot with display issues using only GMap with jQM).

I'm able to add polyline on the map and it works just fine. But when I try to use the fitBounds method, it doesn't work. In fact, it zoom out alot. But not on my bounds.

Here is my code :

```
// Added some data, so you can understand the structure
// of variable "plan"
plan[0].lat_a = 45.4681;    plan[0].lng_a = -73.7414;
plan[0].lat_b = 45.6797;    plan[0].lng_b = -74.0386;
plan[1].lat_a = 45.6797;    plan[1].lng_a = -74.0386;
plan[1].lat_b = 48.7753;    plan[1].lng_b = -64.4786;

var polylinesCoords = new Array();
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Starting point
var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(plan[0].lat_a, plan[0].lng_a);
bounds.extend(LatLng);

// Building the polyline coords and bounds
for (var x=0; x<plan.length; x++) {
    polylinesCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(plan[x].lat_a, plan[x].lng_a), new google.maps.LatLng(plan[x].lat_b, plan[x].lng_b));
    LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(plan[x].lat_b, plan[x].lng_b);
    bounds.extend(LatLng);
}

// Drawing polyline on map
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addShape', 'Polyline', {
    'path': polylinesCoords,
    'strokeColor': '#c00',
    'strokeThickness': 5
});

// «Focus» map on polyline with bounds
var map = $("#map_canvas").gmap("get", "map");
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Everything in this snippet seems to works fine, except for the very last line.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I've looked at the vanilla fitBounds and found out that it forces at least a 45-pixel padding between your "bounds" variable and the edge of the map. I'm not sure what this padding is for mobile, but it might be why it is zooming out.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to set a bigger map. I'm at a point where I try anything.

But my viewport has 200px in height (and way more large). Even if I remove 45 pixel padding, I still have 110px left. 

What I see when it's fully zoomed out, may be at most 10 px width & height. Mostly a small spot on the World Map.

Comment: Even with a map of 450px x 450px that didn't worked. :(

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I really don't work with maps on mobile, just tried a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might've missed to center the map to any of your pin. I got your code working with this line of code

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'center', (new google.maps.LatLng(plan[0].lat_a,plan[0].lng_a)));
```